# SA passport holder with Schengen visa 5 year multiple entry (EU family member) wishes to travel to EU without spouse

Tags: schengen, eu, family

I'm a non EU passport holder and have a valid Schengen visa (5 year multiple entry). When I applied for the visa I applied as a spouse on a UK passport holder. Have traveled to EU several times with my husband and child - no problems. I now wish to travel without my spouse (but with child who has UK passport) on this Schengen. Is this possible?

I realise that conditions for granting the family visa include travelling with partner but it's not clear if these conditions apply for all future travel too. Hoping a Schengen is a Schengen and other conditions can't be applied post issuing. Failing that, hoping my UK born child can be considered my family member.

Comment: By SA you mean South Africa ?

Comment: Also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51192/travel-on-a-schengen-visa-stating-eea-family-member-without-spouse

Comment: The marked duplicate is not at all appropriate. It is an entirely different question that is not helpful to the asker of this question.  The question cited by Gayot Fow is more relevant.

Comment: What is the exact type of visa you have? Have you been officially recognized as a family member of an EU national?

Comment: Also, your statement "have traveled to EU several times with my..." is confusing here. The UK is part of the EU. Where are you resident?