# Can non-EU with Family Member Schengen visa travel alone?

Tags: visas, schengen

My son is an EU citizen but I am not.

A few months ago, I applied for a Schengen visa from the Danish Embassy as an EU Family Member and got my visa. We then traveled to Denmark together as planned.
Now I am going to holiday in Oslo with my sister, but my son is poorly and he will stay here in the UK (where we live).

I have the multiple entry Schengen on my passport, but I am wondering will it be a problem to travel without my son. On the visa itself no restrictions are listed. His name is on the plane ticket though as I booked him for the flight, as well.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51192/travel-on-a-schengen-visa-stating-eea-family-member-without-spouse although that one talks about a spouse

Comment: Hi, this is actually is NOT a duplicate question. I have seen that thread but my condition is not the same. My visa does not state 'EEA family member' on it. But when I was applying from the Denmark vfs visa center, in London they told me I HAVE TO travel with my son.

Comment: anyway I have done the travel now and no one asked me about my son.  And did not have any problems. This travel was on one of the multiple plans when I applied for this schengen. Just in case someone has the same question some time. Thanks.

Comment: Ova, perhaps you should add an answer to the so-called duplicate question, and link to it here in a comment.

Comment: Hello phoog, I have already added the comment - which I think answers my own question :)
I was told by Denmark Vfs worker that I have to travel with my son (who is EU citizen) and I traveled to Copenhag with him. But the second travel to Oslo -which was also included in the application- I have not take my son and they did not ask anything about him.. Hope this helps someone .But I must add, my visa is normal C type multiple entry and does not say anything about an Eu family member.